# Importing python modules from other packages with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a folder structure of

- src

  - Snakefile
  - scripts

    - scripts_A

      - A.py
      - A2.py
    - scripts_B

      - B.py

In A.py I have the import statements

import A2
from src.scripts.scripts_B.B import B

This works when I run A as a script normally. However when I try a snakefile with rule

rule stuff:
input: a_in
output: b_out
script: scripts/scripts_A/A.py

it fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

I've tried  changing location of Snakefile to be above and below src